# How to pass a generator to create threading.Thread and get access on elements of generator in an array of parameters

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

In python2, I would like to launch 16 `threading.Thread` from `import threading` library. For each launch, I try to pass as parameters a generator to the function `buildCrossMatrix_loop` which is the target function

Maybe I have to do a conversion of generator to convert into 1D array or list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function expects a list. You are giving it a generator. You have to adapt either the function to take a generator or pass the function a list.

Comment: I tried to convert with : `p = threading.Thread(target=buildCrossMatrix_loop, args=(list(generatorCrossMatrix(i)),))`and `p = threading.Thread(target=buildCrossMatrix_loop, args=(list(generatorCrossMatrix(i))))`but both give the same error, how do you pass the generator as a list when creating `threading.Thread` ?